# Compare multiple rows to pick the one with smallest value

Tags: linux, bash, awk, compare, row

I would like to compare the rows in the second column, and get the row with the highest value in the consecutive columns, with priority of `column 3> 4 > 5`. I sorted my dataset for the second column so the same values will be together.
My dataset looks like this:

```
X1    A 0.38 24.68  2.93
X2    A 0.38 20.22 14.54
X3    A 0.38 20.08 00.48
X3.3  A 0.22 11.55 10.68
C43   B 0.22 11.55 20.08
C4.2  C 0.22 11.55  3.08
C4.5  C 0.22 11.55 31.08
C42   D 0.96 21.15 11.24
C44   D 0.22  1.10  1.24
P1    E 0.42  0.42  0.42
P2    E 0.42  0.42  0.42
P3    E 0.42  0.42  0.42
```

In here, I would like to say, if `second column` is the same value with another row, then I compare their values in the `third column` and pick the row with the highest value in the `third column`.

If the rows have the same `second and third columns`, then I go to `forth column` and compare their values in this column, and then get row with the highest value.

If the rows sharing `second column` still share the values in `third and forth columns`, then I pick the row with highest value in the `fifth column.`

If, `second-third-forth-fifth columns` are the same (complete duplicates), then I print them all, but add `'duplicate'` next to their fifth column.

If a row does not share its value for the second column for any other rows, then there is no comparison and I keep this column.

Therefore, my expected output will be:

```
X1    A 0.38 24.68  2.93
C43   B 0.22 11.55 20.08
C4.5  C 0.22 11.55 31.08
C42   D 0.96 21.15 11.24
P1    E 0.42  0.42  0.42duplicate
P2    E 0.42  0.42  0.42duplicate
P3    E 0.42  0.42  0.42duplicate
```

What I tried at the moment fails, because I can only compare based on second column and not with multiple columns conditioning and I cannot keep complete duplicates.

```
cat data.txt | awk -v OFS="\t" '$1=$1' | sort -k2,2 -k3nr -k4nr -k5nr  | awk '!a[$2]++'
X1      A       0.38    24.68   2.93
C43     B       0.22    11.55   20.08
C4.5    C       0.22    11.55   31.08
C42     D       0.96    21.15   11.24
P1      E       0.42    0.42    0.42
```

I appreciate to learn how to fix it.

Comment: They are actually considered the same, because X3.3 has an A in the second column and `X3.3` has the lowest value in its 3rd column, compared to others with an `A` in their second column: `(X1,X2,X3)`. Therefore it has already "lost" the competition against them, and now I should compare `X1,X2 and X3`.  I hope it was helpful?

Comment: Not important but really don't you want a space between the data and the word 'duplicate'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the code below is not sophisticated, how about:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '$1=$1' "data.txt" | sort -k2,2 -k3nr -k4nr -k5nr > "tmp.txt"

awk -v OFS="\t" '
    NR==FNR {
        vals = $3","$4","$5
        if (max[$2] == "") max[$2] = vals
        else if (max[$2] == vals) dupe[$2] = 1
        next
    } {
        vals = $3","$4","$5
        if (dupe[$2]) $6 = "duplicate"
        if (max[$2] == vals) print
    }' "tmp.txt" "tmp.txt"

rm -f "tmp.txt"
```

- It saves the sorted result in a temporary file "tmp.txt".
- The 2nd `awk` script processes the temporary file with two passes.
- In the 1st pass, it extracts the "max value" for each 2nd column.
- It also detects the duplications and set the variable `dupe` if found.
- In the 2nd pass, it assigns the variable `$6` to a string `duplicate`
  if the line has the dupe flag.
- Then it prints only the line(s) which have the max value for each 2nd column.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most elegant solution but it works

```
cat data.txt | awk -v OFS="\t" '$1=$1' | sort -k2,2 -k3nr -k4nr -k5nr  | awk '!a[$2]++' |  cut -f2-  > /tmp/fgrep.$$
cat data.txt | fgrep -f /tmp/fgrep.$$ | awk '{
  rec[NR] = $0
  idx = sprintf("%s %s %s %s",$2,$3,$4,$5)
  irec[NR] = idx
  dup[idx]++
}
END{
  for(i in rec){
    if(dup[irec[i]]> 1){
      print rec[i] "duplicate"
    }else{
      print rec[i]
    }
  }
}'
rm /tmp/fgrep.$$
```